# How to create a minimal repository of needed tested packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

What is the best way to create a local repository of packages that are needed to operate an own application? Currently all packages were synced and the versions are frozen. What is the best way to get only new packages (that have to be tested) that are needed in order to avoid testing all?